# CMake - usd_from_gltf - Error could not load cache

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, build, usd

I've trying to build https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf.
Since I am not experienced with CMake and Visual Studio I followed the instructions and managed to work after some fixes.

Now I am stuck in an issue that does not look like a problem related to the package.
I got this error in my log.txt:

```
cmake H:\usd_from_gltf-master -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=H:\UFG-CP37 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=H:\UFG-CP37 -DUSD_DIR=H:\USD-CP27 -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: H:/usd_from_gltf-master
cmake --build . --config Release --target install -- /m
Error: could not load cache
```

I wonder if this problem is related to the package versions. Feels like a problem related to my computer itself. Maybe someone can clear this a bit for me. I have seen some SO questions and some related to the build tree, but I am unsure about this.

Windows 10 x64 | USD 21.02 built using Python2.7 | usd_from_gltf using Python3.7 | Visual Studio 2017

My command was:

```
H:\usd_from_gltf-master>python ./tools/ufginstall/ufginstall.py H:/UFG-CP37 H:/USD-CP27 --testdata
```

Where as H:/UFG-CP37 I want it to be built and USD-CP27 is my USD Build.

Comment: Please, learn how to format your posts on Stack Overflow. E.g. formatting as a code is easy: 1. Select the code you want to format. 2. Press `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: OK! Sorry about that and thanks!

Comment: It looks like the working dir (.) is not a valid build directory because it does not contain a CMakeCache.txt file. Maybe the script changes the working directory underneath. What happens if you take the instructions literally and run the program with a full path to the `usd_from_gltf` dir, i.e. `python H:/usd_from_gltf-master/tools/ufginstall/ufginstall.py H:/UFG-CP37 H:/USD-CP27 --testdata`?

Comment: If `cmake H:\usd_from_gltf-master -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=H:\UFG-CP37 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=H:\UFG-CP37 -DUSD_DIR=H:\USD-CP27 -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64` is the command that's run it's definetly missing something. There should at least be a source dir listed, even if it's just `.` Maybe cmake behaves different to the behavior described in the docs and tries to reconfigure the current working directory. Are you sure you're passing all necessary parameters to the script?

Comment: After checking the `usd_from_gltf` project I suppose you see the errors because you are doing an in source build. I saw a `delete_directory_content(build_dir)` in the script you are calling, so at present your combined source/build directory is wiped after CMake configuration just before you build. Create a separate build directory `mkdir build` and change to that directory `cd build` and run the command `python H:/usd_from_gltf-master/tools/ufginstall/ufginstall.py H:/UFG-CP37 H:/USD-CP27 --testdata` from there.

Comment: OK! @fabian I am pretty sure I passed all the parameters, following guides as stands like this: python {UFG_SRC}/tools/ufginstall/ufginstall.py {UFG_BUILD} {USD} --testdata

Comment: Hello, @vre! Thanks for going further and checking the source.
I did it exactly as you asked. Tried changing to build directory and running from there. The problem persisted. I will try building using Python 2.7 and post here the results.